# how to flatten out webapi EF using DTO and linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to flatten out my webapi EF using a DTO and linq but not quite sure how to do it.  My end goal is to say, I want to return ALL four accounts where USERNAME = x.

In this example there is 1 username with access to 1 client, and that 1 client has 4 accounts.

How can I make the result come back with 4 entries, 1 for each account?

Here is what I have so far...

```
            var x2 = from b in db.AspNetUsers
                 where b.UserName == username
                 select new AspNetUserDetailDTO()
                 {
                     UserName = b.UserName,
                     Email = b.Email,
                     Mapping_UserClient = b.Mapping_UserClient
                     //ClientName = b.Mapping_UserClient.SelectMany<Mapping_UserClient>(x => x.ClientID)
                     //Mapping_UserClient = b.Mapping_UserClient
                 };
```

below is my sql diagram.

[image: sql diagram]

so I tried writing a plain sql query to return a basic result of what I am looking for... now I do not know how to do this in LINQ

```
SELECT 
dbo.Clients.ClientName
,dbo.Mapping_UserClient.ClientID
,*
 FROM [xxx].[dbo].[AspNetUsers]
 inner join dbo.Mapping_UserClient on     dbo.Mapping_UserClient.AspNetUsersID    = dbo.AspNetUsers.Id
 inner join dbo.Clients on dbo.Clients.ClientID =   dbo.Mapping_UserClient.ClientID
 inner join dbo.Mapping_ClientAccount on dbo.Mapping_ClientAccount.ClientID    = dbo.Clients.ClientID
 inner join dbo.Accounts on dbo.Accounts.AccountID =   dbo.Mapping_ClientAccount.AccountID
```

where Email = 'dddd'

Comment: Write out SQL version so you can know how to achieve that result and try to write the Linq version of the SQL that provided the desired results.

Comment: I would start from the table you want data from (Accounts). Then, you have to go back through your relationship until you reach the table where your username field is located (AspNetUsers) I think.

Comment: thanks @Nkosi, I wrote a sql query... now how can I transfer that to LINQ?

Comment: @jpgrassi  I could do that to but I don't know how to write adjust my class that would go backwards like that in my chain

Comment: is starting with the table I want the data from the BEST PRACTICE way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your query above, you would get something like this in Linq:

```
var query = (from acc in db.Accounts
             join mca in db.Mapping_ClientAccount
                on acc.AccountId equals mca.ClientID
             join cli in db.Clients
                on mca.ClientID equals cli.ClientID
             join muc in db.Mapping_UserClient
                on cli.ClientID equals muc.ClientID
             join anu in db.AspNetUsers
                on muc.AspNetUsersID equals anu.Id
            where anu.UserName == username
            select new AspNetUserDetailsDTO()
            {
                ClientName = cli.ClientName,
                ClientID = cli.ClientID
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: am I even going about this the correct way or should I figure out how to start with table I want data from?

Comment: I would start from Accounts since you want the data from it. This way you avoid looking for more things than you actually need.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but is the answer you posted above STARTING from Accounts?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can see it: "from acc in db.Accounts". Usually in Inner Join's the order doesn't matter much, although whenever I can, I prefer to start from the table I want data from. But for Left, Right, it does matter, a lot.

Comment: thank you. I took your advice, I started from Accounts and created a query based on how you listed above and I am now able to have each Account returned successfully.  thanks!